# Client traffic is not routed throught VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, strongswan

I try to create a simple Strongswan connection between a server and an Android phone, using Strongswan Android application.

My Android phone informations :
`Android 8.0.0` with Samsung Experience 9.0
It's a Galaxy A5 (2017) model

I tried using both 4G and Wifi
My Strongswan app is on `version 2.3.0`, updated on june 2020

My server informations :
It's an `Ubuntu 18.04` VPS up-to-date

My Strongswan server configuration is as follow
I downloaded manually `Strongswan 5.9.0` and then configured it using

```
./configure --prefix=/custompath/strongroot --disable-stroke --with-piddir=/custompath/strongroot/var/run --enable-eap-dynamic --enable-eap-mschapv2 --enable-eap-aka --enable-eap-identity --enable-md4
make
make install
```

My strongswan.conf is as follow

```
charon {
        load_modular = yes

        plugins {

                include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
        }
}

include strongswan.d/*.conf
```

My server-side swanctl.conf is as follow

```
connections {
       server {
                pools = primary-pool-ipv4, primary-pool-ipv6
                local {
                        auth = pubkey
                        certs = <server_crt>
                        id = <server_id>
                }
                remote {
                        auth = eap-dynamic
                        id = %any
                }

                children {
                    client {

                    }
                }
        }
}


secrets {
        eap-test {
                id = <user_id>
                secret = <user_password>
        }
}


pools {
    primary-pool-ipv4 {
        addrs = 10.0.0.0/24
        dns = 8.8.8.8 
    }
    primary-pool-ipv6 {
        addrs = 2620:0:2d0:200::7/97

    }
}
```

Server is launched with following command as root with those results

```
/custompath/strongroot/libexec/ipsec/charon &
/custompath/strongroot/sbin/swanctl -q


loaded certificate from '/custompath/strongroot/etc/swanctl/x509/<server_crt'
loaded certificate from '/custompath/strongroot/etc/swanctl/x509ca/<CA_crt>'
loaded rsa key from '/custompath/strongroot/etc/swanctl/private/<server_key>'
loaded eap secret 'eap-test'
no authorities found, 0 unloaded
loaded pool 'primary-pool-ipv4'
loaded pool 'primary-pool-ipv6'
successfully loaded 2 pools, 0 unloaded
loaded connection 'server'
successfully loaded 1 connections, 0 unloaded
```

and those logs

```
[CFG] loaded certificate 'C=FR, O=Test, CN=<server_id>'
[CFG] loaded certificate 'C=FR, O=Test, CN=Test CA'
[CFG] loaded RSA private key
[CFG] loaded EAP shared key with id 'eap-test' for: '<user_id>'
[CFG] added vici pool primary-pool-ipv4: 10.0.0.0, 254 entries
[CFG] added vici pool primary-pool-ipv6: 2620:0:2d0:200::7, 2147483640 entries
[CFG] added vici connection: server
```

On my android phone, I used following parameters on my Strongswan App

```
Server : <server ipv4>
VPN Type : IKEv2 EAP (Username/Password)
Username : <user_id>
Password <user_password>

CA certificate : <CA_crt>

Server identity : <server_id>
Client identity : <user_id>
```

When I log my client to the server I got following logs on server :

```
[NET] <3> received packet: from  <client_ip>[33980] to   <server_ip>[500] (716 bytes)
[ENC] <3> parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
[IKE] <3>  <client_ip> is initiating an IKE_SA
[CFG] <3> selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_AES128_XCBC/CURVE_25519
[IKE] <3> remote host is behind NAT
[IKE] <3> DH group ECP_256 unacceptable, requesting CURVE_25519
[ENC] <3> generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
[NET] <3> sending packet: from   <server_ip>[500] to  <client_ip>[33980] (38 bytes)
[NET] <4> received packet: from  <client_ip>[33980] to   <server_ip>[500] (684 bytes)
[ENC] <4> parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
[IKE] <4>  <client_ip> is initiating an IKE_SA
[CFG] <4> selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_AES128_XCBC/CURVE_25519
[IKE] <4> remote host is behind NAT
[IKE] <4> sending cert request for "C=FR, O=Test, CN=Test CA"
[ENC] <4> generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) CERTREQ N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(CHDLESS_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
[NET] <4> sending packet: from   <server_ip>[500] to  <client_ip>[33980] (273 bytes)
[NET] <4> received packet: from  <client_ip>[51380] to   <server_ip>[4500] (480 bytes)
[ENC] <4> parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) CERTREQ IDr CPRQ(ADDR ADDR6 DNS DNS6) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(NO_ADD_ADDR) N(MULT_AUTH) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
[IKE] <4> received cert request for "C=FR, O=Test, CN=Test CA"
[CFG] <4> looking for peer configs matching   <server_ip>[<server_id>]... <client_ip>[<client_id>]
[CFG] <server|4> selected peer config 'server'
[IKE] <server|4> EAP_AKA method selected
[IKE] <server|4> initiating EAP_AKA method (id 0x11)
[IKE] <server|4> received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
[IKE] <server|4> peer supports MOBIKE
[IKE] <server|4> authentication of '<server_id>' (myself) with RSA_EMSA_PKCS1_SHA2_256 successful
[IKE] <server|4> sending end entity cert "C=FR, O=Test, CN=<server_id>"
[ENC] <server|4> generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/AKA ]
[NET] <server|4> sending packet: from   <server_ip>[4500] to  <client_ip>[51380] (1184 bytes)
[NET] <server|4> received packet: from  <client_ip>[51380] to   <server_ip>[4500] (80 bytes)
[ENC] <server|4> parsed IKE_AUTH request 2 [ EAP/RES/NAK ]
[IKE] <server|4> received EAP_NAK, selecting a different EAP method
[IKE] <server|4> EAP_MSCHAPV2 method selected
[ENC] <server|4> generating IKE_AUTH response 2 [ EAP/REQ/MSCHAPV2 ]
[NET] <server|4> sending packet: from   <server_ip>[4500] to  <client_ip>[51380] (112 bytes)
[NET] <server|4> received packet: from  <client_ip>[51380] to   <server_ip>[4500] (144 bytes)
[ENC] <server|4> parsed IKE_AUTH request 3 [ EAP/RES/MSCHAPV2 ]
[ENC] <server|4> generating IKE_AUTH response 3 [ EAP/REQ/MSCHAPV2 ]
[NET] <server|4> sending packet: from   <server_ip>[4500] to  <client_ip>[51380] (144 bytes)
[NET] <server|4> received packet: from  <client_ip>[51380] to   <server_ip>[4500] (80 bytes)
[ENC] <server|4> parsed IKE_AUTH request 4 [ EAP/RES/MSCHAPV2 ]
[IKE] <server|4> EAP method EAP_MSCHAPV2 succeeded, MSK established
[ENC] <server|4> generating IKE_AUTH response 4 [ EAP/SUCC ]
[NET] <server|4> sending packet: from   <server_ip>[4500] to  <client_ip>[51380] (80 bytes)
[NET] <server|4> received packet: from  <client_ip>[51380] to   <server_ip>[4500] (96 bytes)
[ENC] <server|4> parsed IKE_AUTH request 5 [ AUTH ]
[IKE] <server|4> authentication of '<client_id>' with EAP successful
[IKE] <server|4> authentication of '<server_id>' (myself) with EAP
[IKE] <server|4> IKE_SA server[4] established between   <server_ip>[<server_id>]... <client_ip>[<client_id>]
[IKE] <server|4> scheduling rekeying in 13701s
[IKE] <server|4> maximum IKE_SA lifetime 15141s
[IKE] <server|4> peer requested virtual IP %any
[CFG] <server|4> reassigning offline lease to '<client_id>'
[IKE] <server|4> assigning virtual IP 10.0.0.1 to peer '<client_id>'
[IKE] <server|4> peer requested virtual IP %any6
[CFG] <server|4> reassigning offline lease to '<client_id>'
[IKE] <server|4> assigning virtual IP 2620:0:2d0:200::7 to peer '<client_id>'
[CFG] <server|4> selected proposal: ESP:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/NO_EXT_SEQ
[JOB] watched FD 15 ready to read
[JOB] watcher going to poll() 3 fds
[JOB] watcher got notification, rebuilding
[JOB] watcher going to poll() 4 fds
[IKE] <server|4> CHILD_SA client{2} established with SPIs ce546f2f_i 58d283b4_o and TS   <server_ip>/32 === 10.0.0.1/32 2620:0:2d0:200::7/128
[ENC] <server|4> generating IKE_AUTH response 5 [ AUTH CPRP(ADDR ADDR6 DNS) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(NO_ADD_ADDR) ]
[NET] <server|4> sending packet: from   <server_ip>[4500] to  <client_ip>[51380] (288 bytes)
```

And those logs on client-side

```
[DMN] +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
[DMN] Starting IKE service (strongSwan 5.8.4, Android 8.0.0 - R16NW.A520FXXSFCTG8/2020-08-01, SM-A520F - samsung/a5y17ltexx/samsung, Linux 3.18.14-13712092-QB33307948, aarch64)
[LIB] loaded plugins: androidbridge charon android-log openssl fips-prf random nonce pubkey chapoly curve25519 pkcs1 pkcs8 pem xcbc hmac socket-default revocation eap-identity eap-mschapv2 eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-tls x509
[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
[IKE] initiating IKE_SA android[2] to <server_ip>
[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
[NET] sending packet: from <client_internal_ip>[33980] to <server_ip>[500] (716 bytes)
[NET] received packet: from <server_ip>[500] to <client_internal_ip>[33980] (38 bytes)
[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
[IKE] peer didn't accept DH group ECP_256, it requested CURVE_25519
[IKE] initiating IKE_SA android[2] to <server_ip>
[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
[NET] sending packet: from <client_internal_ip>[33980] to <server_ip>[500] (684 bytes)
[NET] received packet: from <server_ip>[500] to <client_internal_ip>[33980] (273 bytes)
[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) CERTREQ N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(CHDLESS_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
[CFG] selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_AES128_XCBC/CURVE_25519
[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
[IKE] received cert request for "C=FR, O=Test, CN=Test CA"
[IKE] sending cert request for "C=FR, O=Test, CN=Test CA"
[IKE] establishing CHILD_SA android{2}
[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) CERTREQ IDr CPRQ(ADDR ADDR6 DNS DNS6) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(NO_ADD_ADDR) N(MULT_AUTH) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
[NET] sending packet: from <client_internal_ip>[51380] to <server_ip>[4500] (480 bytes)
[NET] received packet: from <server_ip>[4500] to <client_internal_ip>[51380] (1184 bytes)
[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/AKA ]
[IKE] received end entity cert "C=FR, O=Test, CN=<server_id>"
[CFG]   using certificate "C=FR, O=Test, CN=<server_id>"
[CFG]   using trusted ca certificate "C=FR, O=Test, CN=Test CA"
[CFG] checking certificate status of "C=FR, O=Test, CN=<server_id>"
[CFG] certificate status is not available
[CFG]   reached self-signed root ca with a path length of 0
[IKE] authentication of '<server_id>' with RSA_EMSA_PKCS1_SHA2_256 successful
[IKE] server requested EAP_AKA authentication (id 0x11)
[IKE] EAP method not supported, sending EAP_NAK
[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 2 [ EAP/RES/NAK ]
[NET] sending packet: from <client_internal_ip>[51380] to <server_ip>[4500] (80 bytes)
[NET] received packet: from <server_ip>[4500] to <client_internal_ip>[51380] (112 bytes)
[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 2 [ EAP/REQ/MSCHAPV2 ]
[IKE] server requested EAP_MSCHAPV2 authentication (id 0x0F)
[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 3 [ EAP/RES/MSCHAPV2 ]
[NET] sending packet: from <client_internal_ip>[51380] to <server_ip>[4500] (144 bytes)
[NET] received packet: from <server_ip>[4500] to <client_internal_ip>[51380] (144 bytes)
[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 3 [ EAP/REQ/MSCHAPV2 ]
[IKE] EAP-MS-CHAPv2 succeeded: 'Welcome2strongSwan'
[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 4 [ EAP/RES/MSCHAPV2 ]
[NET] sending packet: from <client_internal_ip>[51380] to <server_ip>[4500] (80 bytes)
[NET] received packet: from <server_ip>[4500] to <client_internal_ip>[51380] (80 bytes)
[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 4 [ EAP/SUCC ]
[IKE] EAP method EAP_MSCHAPV2 succeeded, MSK established
[IKE] authentication of '<client_id>' (myself) with EAP
[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 5 [ AUTH ]
[NET] sending packet: from <client_internal_ip>[51380] to <server_ip>[4500] (96 bytes)
[NET] received packet: from <server_ip>[4500] to <client_internal_ip>[51380] (288 bytes)
[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 5 [ AUTH CPRP(ADDR ADDR6 DNS) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(NO_ADD_ADDR) ]
[IKE] authentication of '<server_id>' with EAP successful
[IKE] IKE_SA android[2] established between <client_internal_ip>[<client_id>]...<server_ip>[<server_id>]
[IKE] scheduling rekeying in 35866s
[IKE] maximum IKE_SA lifetime 37666s
[IKE] installing DNS server 8.8.8.8
[IKE] installing new virtual IP 10.0.0.1
[IKE] installing new virtual IP 2620:0:2d0:200::7
[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/NO_EXT_SEQ
[IKE] CHILD_SA android{2} established with SPIs 58d283b4_i ce546f2f_o and TS 10.0.0.1/32 2620:0:2d0:200::7/128 === <server_ip>/32
[DMN] setting up TUN device for CHILD_SA android{2}
[DMN] successfully created TUN device
[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
```

And I got the notification that the tunnel is up.

I added some iptables rules for forwarding with following commands based on this link `https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling` I got only 1 server network interface (not counting loopback) which will be named **<server_int>**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o <server_int> -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o <server_int> -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
```

I also activated the ip forwarding for ipv4 (and ipv6 if it's the correct way) by uncommenting following lines on `/etc/sysctl.conf`

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

and then using `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf` to reload the config

But, when I check my IP online, I see that I still got the client public ip instead of the server one.
What makes me believe that nothing is routed on the VPN is that when I activate the options to disable every traffic outside of the VPN, I loose all connection to the internet (except the VPN one which is still up). But I did not touched the split-tunneling, which by default should redirect everything onto the VPN tunnel.

Which part did I missed here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reach more than the server via VPN tunnel, then you have to specify that in the traffic selectors. That is, change the child config as follows:

```
client {
    local_ts = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
}
```

The default value is *dynamic* and that will default to the IP address (or virtual IP in case of the client), which you can see in the logs (e.g. on the client as `10.0.0.1/32 2620:0:2d0:200::7/128 === <server_ip>/32`).

Comment: I added this modification to my child config on the server side and now I got those logs 
14[IKE] CHILD_SA client{1} established with SPIs cbc0b057_i a1c64a08_o and TS 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0 === 10.0.0.1/32 2620:0:2d0:200::7/128 (client-side says the same)
So it seems that the correct ts has been made, but I still got no access to the internet on my phone when VPN is up and all traffic goes through the VPN

Comment: Might be a problem with your firewall rules. Please post the output of `iptables-save` and `ip6tables-save`. Maybe also check if traffic reaches the server (e.g. via traffic counters in `swanctl -l` or even via `tcpdump`).

Comment: Ok so when I tried to log you the infos, I found what went wrong. It seems that I did not applied correctly my iptables rules as they vanished. Putting them back it now works properly, thanks !